# Oracle: What should be better, alter table CACHE or INDEXES?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, performance, performance-tuning

I have a database (700 tables / 400GB) running on a VM with 64GB of RAM on a physical server with 384GB of RAM, the database has some indexes on some table fields, but it hasn't a good performance.

That physical server was reserved to run databases only, so I could allocate as memory as necessary on it to get a good performance.

I've been reading about tuning and realized that I could put all non-securefile (blob) tables on memory using the CACHE or KEEP POOL parameter, or create a lot of indexes.

What should I do to make queries run faster on it? CACHE or INDEXES?

Comment: Have you used ASH/AWR to diagnose why the performance is slow?

Comment: Mostly it says to create indexes. I am looking at the enterprise manager, the express edition.

Comment: I installed the EM CC 13c, but I dont really understand that interface, the express edition is clear and give me that tips about creating indexes and, in some cases, trying to change the execution plan. But I can try to get some information there (cc 13c) if that is necessary.

Comment: It makes sense to put a table in `KEEP POOL` if it's small , and it's frequently accessed with full table scan.  Also, I'd never run production server on VM, no matter how good it is.

Comment: But, what if I have enough memory to load all non-securefile tables on? Shouldn't I create indexes for that cached tables, right?

Comment: If I create a lot of indexes to accelerate any query, probably I will have problems on updates, right?

Comment: Are you a DBA? Somebody needs to index the data PROPERLY before you think about any further tuning.

Comment: <img whynotboth.jpg>

Comment: The documentation says "Restriction on CACHE:
You cannot specify CACHE for an index-organized table. However, index-organized tables implicitly provide CACHE behavior." That is why, probably, I cannot use both (if I have understood correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

indexes and caching serve different purposes:

1. indexes allow you to read only a (hopefully small) part of the table.
2. Caching reduces the time it takes to read a block as you only need logical (in buffer) reads instead of disk reads.

The two mix very well together as Oracle would happily use a cached index if it fits the query and statistics.

For example reading 10 rows via index will be faster then scanning 40gb table in memory, and if the index is cached then even more so.